# ssl handshake error issue Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, sslhandshakeexception

I hope you are well. My issue is SSL handshake failure. I attempted to obtain the requests parameter with VERIFY=FALSE, updating the requests library, getting a pem certificate file from the browser and setting it to the verify option of get requests, and installing libraries like openssl idna ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
Nevertheless, SSL HANDSHAKE failure persists and all solutions are ineffective. I've switched from using https to http, which functions but i have to use https. this url is not have problem in chrome but in python it raise ssl handshake error

my os: windows 10
python: 3.11.6
requests: 2.31.0

thanks for your answers

Comment: Add the code you have tried and post the full error message you are getting.